# Reference is not defined in the table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, natbib, citetalias

I cited a reference unsing `\citetalias` in a section, but the reference is not displayed in the Table of Contents **`(alias?)`**. I defined the alias in before the section according to the [natbib reference](https://ctan.org/pkg/natbib?lang=de) `\defcitealias{ref_year}{[a]}`.

Is there a way to show the reference also in the ToC?

**Edit** The MWE looks like this (adapted from @moewe):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[numbers, super, sort&compress, square]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{angew}

\begin{document}
    
    \tableofcontents
    
    \defcitealias{doody}{[a]}
    
    \section{Lorem \citetalias{doody}}
    Lorem \cite{doody} Lorem \citetalias{doody}
    
    \bibliographystyle{plainnat}
    \bibliography{biblatex-examples}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works fine for me in the following simple example: https://gist.github.com/moewew/f41b11015aea1cb7d99fda400d20ce77. Please consider posting a fully compilable yet minimal example document that reproduces the issue with as little code as possible.

Comment: Do you use `\defcitealias` in the document body? If so, do you only use it after `\tableofcontents`? It is probably best to issue all `\defcitealias` calls in the preamble so that they are available everywhere.

Comment: @moewe As simple as it is, it works excellent.

Comment: Please show the actual `\section` command that contains the `\citetalias` directive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the following example all `\citetalias` calls work just fine.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage{natbib}
\defcitealias{doody}{[a]}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Lorem \citetalias{doody}}
Lorem \citet{doody} \citetalias{doody}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}
\end{document}
```

[image: "Lorem Doody [1974] [a]" in text and "Lorem [a]" in section heading and ToC.]

The `\defcitealias` needs to be available when `\citetalias` is used, so in order to avoid weird effects, it is probably easiest to make all `\defcitealias` definitions in the preamble.